# I am trying to figure out what is wrong here

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing some code and I keep getting the error of "document.getElementsByClassName".  Here is my code.  What could be wrong?`

```
$("#pre-order").change(function(){   updateDisplay();})
function updateDisplay(){
 var preo = document.getElementsByClassName('product-single__meta');
 preo.addClass('preorder');
 }
 updateDisplay();
```

Comment: getElement(**s**)ByClassName so it returns array not single object. and for the objects in the array there is no method addClass but there is a property named classList where you and add remove classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you combining jquery with regular javascript. you could do

```
var preo = $('.product-single__meta');
```

or even better. one liner

```
$('.product-single__meta').addClass('preOrder');
```

Comment: so how would I turn the class off unless the id of pre-order is present?

Comment: After the above code the element will be '<span class="product-single__meta preOrder"></span>'. What class are you removing? If you want to remove preOrder class if it exists then do $('.product-single__meta.preOrder').removeClass('preOrder');

Answer (score 0):

That does add the class but when the id of pre-order is not present I don't need the preorder class .

Comment: Can you explain what not present means? not present in the HTML element?